# Classes with interfaces in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, class, dependency-injection

Is it bad practice to use class as type in typescript?
Is it good practice to create class from interface and when we need a type somewhere just to use interface, and when we need a method, us DI to inject class;

interface:

[image: interface]

class:

[image: class]